printing svg causes image to resize
I used inkscape 1.3.2 to create an svg that is 215.9 x 279.4mm (8.5x11in). The svg contains nothing but a single bitmap and nothing else. The bitmap is sized to 63 x 88mm. When I print this file in any program, the printed size of the bitmap changes. I've tried printing in different programs, and the only thing I can say is it is consistently off. The printed dimensions of the bitmap are 55 x 77mm in every program I've tried. I don't understand what is causing it to resize the image.
I'm not sure if this matters, but I'm using Kubuntu 22.04, and I've tried printing in Libreoffice Draw, Waterfox, Brave, and Opera. In each case, I selected "No Margins" and print at "100% scaling".
The printer is a Brother 3170 laser printer.

An SVG can't contain a bitmap - it is a vector format (its in the name - scalable vector graphic)- and I suspect this difference is key to understand your problem.    It has likely taken a representation of a bitmap and converted it into a vector.    Maybe try exporting it to a PNG.

@davidgo SVG can reference a bitmap. It is imported by the <image> element. See SVG Essentials page 88 or thereabouts.

I just copied and pasted an image from xnview into inkscape, changed the dimensions, and saved it. Like Bob Goddard said, it embedded the bitmap into the svg as xlink:href="data:image/png;base64

I'm not sure what's causing the discrepancy between the size of the images as defined in the svg file (63mm x 88mm) vs. the printed size (60mm x 84mm, 55mm x 77mm, etc.), but I found that if I sized the images in the svg to account for the discrepancy the printed size was correct. So I sized each bitmap to 66mm x 92mm in the svg and everything printed out at 63mm x 88mm.
The printed dimensions of the initial image were 55mm x 77mm. I suspect what happened was because the size of the svg at that time was 8.5 x 11in, the printer - or maybe the different programs I was using - was automatically resizing the image down just a small amount to fit it within the printable dimensions of the printer, since I don't believe this printer can print right to the edge of the paper. That could have caused it to get "squished".
However, the really confusing thing was I then resized the svg to be the exact same size as the original bitmap size (63 x 88mm), and it still printed out at 60 x 84mm. In that case, there should have been no automatic resizing or minimum printer margins or anything else that should have caused that to happen.
